# Clickable (tap) toggle for touch devices when hover/focus/active doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, touch

I have a couple of 'fun' UI pieces I'm looking at which basically reveal more options when you hover over an icon. This works fine and as expected but obviously on mobile it doesn't behave as well.

Oddly the left most (with S/M/L/XL) does open on 'tap' but is difficult to close. Where as the icon based version doesn't open at all, even though it uses the same approach - maybe to do with the `z-index` changing?

Even if the icons are expanded on mobile it's difficult to close. So I wondered if using a Javascript toggle just for touch devices would be a best practice approach? Or is there a simpler solution I'm missing?

I tried the following Javascript but would that start interfering with other touch/hover and 'hybrid' devices with touch screens + hover events?

```
const actions = document.querySelector('.actions');

actions.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  actions.classList.toggle('visble');
});
```

The issue with the above is that it only targets 1 (1 first) instance of the element on the page. As there will be several of this component on a page. I'd need it to just  toggle the class on the one that's clicked. How could I extended this?

Then I guess I'd specify the current hover/focus/active styling in a media query. Then the same but on a class in another media query, like below?

```
@media (hover: hover) { add current hover/focus/active styles here }

@media (hover: none) { add class-based toggle styles }
```

```css
/* Product */

.product-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 64px auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.product-card {
  position: relative;
}

.product-card img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}




/* Quick Buy */

.quick-buy {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  width: 32px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.quick-buy__variant {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .08s .08s ease-out;
  min-width: 12px;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Hover */

.quick-buy__variant:hover {
  color: white;
}

.quick-buy__variant--top    {top: -12px;}
.quick-buy__variant--right  {right: -12px;}
.quick-buy__variant--bottom {bottom: -12px;}
.quick-buy__variant--left   {left: -12px;}

.quick-buy__icon {
  display: flex;
}

.quick-buy__icon svg {
  position: relative;
}

.quick-buy__icon:before {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
/*   top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  transition: height .16s, inset .16s, width .16s;
  width: 32px;
}

.quick-buy:hover .quick-buy__icon:before {
  height: 112px;
  inset: -40px;
  width: 112px;
}

.quick-buy:hover .quick-buy__variant--top     {opacity: 1; top: -24px;}
.quick-buy:hover .quick-buy__variant--right   {opacity: 1; right: -24px;}
.quick-buy:hover .quick-buy__variant--bottom  {opacity: 1; bottom: -24px;}
.quick-buy:hover .quick-buy__variant--left    {opacity: 1; left: -24px;}




/* Options */

.options {
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  transition: transform .12s;
  width: 32px;
}

.options__btn {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .08);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .12s ease-out;
  width: 32px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.options__btn:hover {
  filter: invert(1);
  transition: filter .08s .08s;
}

.options__btn:nth-child(1) {top: -16px;}
.options__btn:nth-child(2) {left: -16px;}
.options__btn:nth-child(3) {bottom: -16px;}

.options__pivot {
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: filter .08s, transform .16s;
  width: 32px;
}

.options__pivot:before {
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Hover */

.options:hover .options__btn {
  z-index: 1;
}

.options:hover .options__btn:nth-child(1) {opacity: 1; top: -32px;}
.options:hover .options__btn:nth-child(2) {opacity: 1; left: -32px;}
.options:hover .options__btn:nth-child(3) {opacity: 1; bottom: -32px;}

.options:hover .options__pivot {
  filter: invert(1);
  transform: scale(.64);
}

.options:hover .options__pivot svg {
  opacity: .48;
}

.options:hover .options__pivot:before {
  height: 144px;
  width: 144px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-grid">
  
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14845056/pexels-photo-14845056.jpeg" />
    <div class="quick-buy">
      <button class="quick-buy__variant quick-buy__variant--top">S</button>
      <button class="quick-buy__variant quick-buy__variant--right">M</button>
      <button class="quick-buy__variant quick-buy__variant--bottom">L</button>
      <button class="quick-buy__variant quick-buy__variant--left">XL</button>
      <span class="quick-buy__icon">
        <svg width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 12 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.96962 4C8.98964 3.8367 9 3.66976 9 3.5C9 1.567 7.65685 0 6 0C4.34315 0 3 1.567 3 3.5C3 3.66976 3.01036 3.8367 3.03038 4H4.03853C4.01338 3.841 4 3.67413 4 3.5C4 1.96911 5.0345 1 6 1C6.9655 1 8 1.96911 8 3.5C8 3.67413 7.98662 3.841 7.96147 4H8.96962Z" fill="white"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="4.5" width="11" height="9" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14845056/pexels-photo-14845056.jpeg" />
    <div class="options">
      <button class="options__btn">
        <svg width="14" height="12" viewBox="0 0 14 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1.85659 1.8436C2.1256 1.57652 2.44674 1.36433 2.80118 1.21947C3.15562 1.07461 3.53624 1 3.92073 1C4.30521 1 4.68583 1.07461 5.04027 1.21947C5.39471 1.36433 5.71585 1.57652 5.98486 1.8436L6.99957 2.84348L8.01428 1.8436C8.28329 1.57652 8.60443 1.36433 8.95887 1.21947C9.31331 1.07461 9.69393 1 10.0784 1C10.4629 1 10.8435 1.07461 11.198 1.21947C11.5524 1.36433 11.8735 1.57652 12.1426 1.8436C12.6922 2.38875 13 3.12167 13 3.88503C13 4.64838 12.6922 5.3813 12.1426 5.92644L7.00043 11L1.85831 5.92644C1.30848 5.38152 1.00032 4.64872 1 3.88537C0.99968 3.12201 1.30722 2.38897 1.85659 1.8436V1.8436Z" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
      </button>
      <button class="options__btn">
        <svg width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 12 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.96962 4C8.98964 3.8367 9 3.66976 9 3.5C9 1.567 7.65685 0 6 0C4.34315 0 3 1.567 3 3.5C3 3.66976 3.01036 3.8367 3.03038 4H4.03853C4.01338 3.841 4 3.67413 4 3.5C4 1.96911 5.0345 1 6 1C6.9655 1 8 1.96911 8 3.5C8 3.67413 7.98662 3.841 7.96147 4H8.96962Z" fill="black"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="4.5" width="11" height="9" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
      </button>
      <button class="options__btn">3D</button>
      <span class="options__pivot">
        <svg width="2" height="10" viewBox="0 0 2 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="1" cy="9" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 9)" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="1" cy="5" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 5)" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 1)" fill="white"/>
</svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/14845056/pexels-photo-14845056.jpeg" />
    <div class="options">
      <button class="options__btn">
        <svg width="14" height="12" viewBox="0 0 14 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1.85659 1.8436C2.1256 1.57652 2.44674 1.36433 2.80118 1.21947C3.15562 1.07461 3.53624 1 3.92073 1C4.30521 1 4.68583 1.07461 5.04027 1.21947C5.39471 1.36433 5.71585 1.57652 5.98486 1.8436L6.99957 2.84348L8.01428 1.8436C8.28329 1.57652 8.60443 1.36433 8.95887 1.21947C9.31331 1.07461 9.69393 1 10.0784 1C10.4629 1 10.8435 1.07461 11.198 1.21947C11.5524 1.36433 11.8735 1.57652 12.1426 1.8436C12.6922 2.38875 13 3.12167 13 3.88503C13 4.64838 12.6922 5.3813 12.1426 5.92644L7.00043 11L1.85831 5.92644C1.30848 5.38152 1.00032 4.64872 1 3.88537C0.99968 3.12201 1.30722 2.38897 1.85659 1.8436V1.8436Z" stroke="black" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</svg>
      </button>
      <button class="options__btn">
        <svg width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 12 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.96962 4C8.98964 3.8367 9 3.66976 9 3.5C9 1.567 7.65685 0 6 0C4.34315 0 3 1.567 3 3.5C3 3.66976 3.01036 3.8367 3.03038 4H4.03853C4.01338 3.841 4 3.67413 4 3.5C4 1.96911 5.0345 1 6 1C6.9655 1 8 1.96911 8 3.5C8 3.67413 7.98662 3.841 7.96147 4H8.96962Z" fill="black"/>
<rect x="0.5" y="4.5" width="11" height="9" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
      </button>
      <span class="options__pivot">
        <svg width="2" height="10" viewBox="0 0 2 10" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="1" cy="9" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 9)" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="1" cy="5" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 5)" fill="white"/>
<circle cx="1" cy="1" r="1" transform="rotate(180 1 1)" fill="white"/>
</svg>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```